# How many principal minors can a $5\times 5$ matrix have?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to know how many principal minors a $5 \times 5$ matrix can have.

I know it would have $5$ diagonal elements as the first order principal minors. I want to know about the higher orders and the total number of principal minors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are in total
$$
\sum_{i=1}^4 {{5}\choose{i}}=5+10+10+5=30
$$
principal minors, since there are ${n}\choose {k}$ principal minors of order $k$ in a $n \times n$ matrix.

Comment: In other words, $2^5 - 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Including the $0\times0$ and $5\times5$ minors, for simplicity, we see that choosing a subset of the columns uniquely determines the principal minor. There are $2^5=32$ distinct subsets of the five columns.

If you don't want the $0\times 0$ and $5\times5$ minors, you can subtract those two to get an answer of $30$.